# weblogic clustering.. setting parameters through startup script for each server

Tags: weblogic

I need to setup separate parameters for each server during the startup.  so application inside the server will use these parameters.  Application will be deployed as an EAR file.

What is the easiest way to do this?  weblogic 10.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Typically what I have done is the reverse of JoseK - have a script called 'startms#.sh' and in that script you can set/export JAVA_OPTIONS and then call startManagedWebLogic.sh.  They should be propogated down to the startManagedWebLogic.sh script unless you have changed that script.

Answer (score 0):

Have the startManagedWeblogic.sh command run a separate sh internally.

That should contain your specific params (one example below)

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Dweblogic.configuration.schemaValidationEnabled=false"

export JAVA_OPTIONS
```

And set these on each server as required

Comment: How do i set parameter unique to each server.  For ex: -DURL for each of these servers? URL is unique to each server (hostname:port#).

Comment: on each server, the internal sh containing the -DURL will be different.